# MySql trigger not working, syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have tried to create the following trigger but it is not working:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteFeature
AFTER DELETE ON Features
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN        
    IF (OLD.FeatureID IN (SELECT FeatureID FROM GroupFeatures)) THEN
      INSERT INTO DeletedFeatures VALUES (OLD.FeatureID, OLD.FeatureName, OLD.FeatureDescription);
    END IF;
END; 
//
```

It is giving the following error:

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 8 "

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: I'm not sure that last "END" needs a `;`

Comment: Just tried taking it out but no joy

Comment: Examples seen here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html Only different, their `BEGIN` is on it's own line.

Comment: Also folllowing the docs : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html
You might need a `BEGIN`

Comment: Can also test at http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I tried BEGIN on its own line but it didnt work.
Could this be an issue with where im entering the trigger? I have selected my database (I can see all my tables), then I clicked the SQL tab and am entering my code there, is that correct?

I have also tried selecting the Features (and the DeletedFeatures) table and then clicking the SQL tab there and entering the code in case that made a difference but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked by removing the semi-colon and add `$$` after the `END`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteFeature
AFTER DELETE ON Features
FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN        
    IF (OLD.FeatureID IN (SELECT FeatureID FROM GroupFeatures)) THEN
      INSERT INTO DeletedFeatures VALUES (OLD.FeatureID, OLD.FeatureName OLD.FeatureDescription);
    END IF;
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can you execute the above and check once again please

Comment: Just executed it and got this error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OLD.FeatureDescription);
    END IF;
   END' at line 6

Comment: Are you missing a comma , in between these two `OLD.FeatureName OLD.FeatureDescription)`

Comment: Yep, I was missing that comma. I put it in and got this error:
#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Ok, would this imply that there is a trigger there already?

Comment: Ok, the trigger is now showing in the triggers tab.
I have no idea how, every single time i tried to enter the code (or so i thought) I got an error. I must have missed something but i really didnt think i did. Im not sure which piece of code actually worked but when I go to edit the trigger this is what shows:

BEGIN        
    IF OLD.FeatureID IN (SELECT FeatureID FROM GroupFeatures) THEN
      INSERT INTO DeletedFeatures VALUES (OLD.FeatureID, OLD.FeatureName, OLD.FeatureDescription);
    END IF;
END

Comment: which is a different issue now. You may have another tigger with the same name. DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS might solve the issue. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,161909,162074#msg-162074.